# Split a string with different condition without removing the character in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string with parameters in it:

```
text =  "Uncertain significance PVS1=0 PS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] PM=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] PP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] BA1=0 BS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] BP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
```

I want to remove spaces to obtain all parameters individually in the following way:

```
pred_res = ["Uncertain significance","PVS1=0","PS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]","PM=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]","PP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]","BA1=0","BS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]","BP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"]
```

So far I have used this regex pattern:

```
pat = re.compile('[a-z]\s[A-Z]|[0-9]\s[A-Z]|]\s[A-Z]')
```

But it's giving me the result in the following way where it removes characters:

```
res = ["Uncertain significanc","VS1=","S=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0","M=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0","P=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0","A1=","S=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0","P=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"]
```

So is there a way to prevent this and obtain the result shown in `pred_res`?

Comment: So you want (list of words) OR (XX=[...]) ? Also you didn't show the regex method that you used on your `pat` pattern

Comment: Maybe `re.split(r'\s+(?=[A-Z])', text)` will do?

Comment: @azro I want the result like **pred_res**. And i used the pattern in Series.str.split(). As i have column with data like variable text. I just used a single example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lookahead to check that there is an `=` in the text immediately following a space.

```
import re
text = 'Uncertain significance PVS1=0 PS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] PM=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] PP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] BA1=0 BS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] BP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]'
pred_res = re.split(r' (?=\w+=)', text)
print(pred_res)
# ['Uncertain significance', 'PVS1=0', 'PS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', 'PM=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', 'PP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', 'BA1=0', 'BS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', 'BP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]']
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked like magic. If its not much trouble can you can explain how did you come up with this pattern?

Comment: @NikhilPanchal There's a brief description of lookaheads here: [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups), but ultimately they're just something you learn at some point, the example used here allows you to search for a string which has another string following (*"Look ahead positive `(?=)`"* on the post linked). The reason I went for a space with = in the following text was that that is where all the splits occured in the string in your example.

Answer (score 3):

Another option could be matching all the separate parts.

```
\w+=(?:\[[^][]*]|[^][\s]+)|\w+(?: \w+)*(?= \w+=|$)
```

- `\w+=` Match 1+ word char followed by `=`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\[[^][]*]` match from `[` till `]`
  - `|` Or
  - `[^][\s]+` Match any char except a whitespace char or char `[` and `]`
- `)` Close the group
- `|` or
- `\w+(?: \w+)*(?= \w+=|$)` Match word chars optionally repeated by a space and word chars asserting word chars followed by `=` or the end of the string at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E0ncMI/1)

```
import re

s = "Uncertain significance PVS1=0 PS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] PM=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] PP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] BA1=0 BS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] BP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
pattern = r"\w+=(?:\[[^][]*]|[^][\s]+)|\w+(?: \w+)*(?= \w+=|$)"

pred_res = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(pred_res)
```

Output

```
['Uncertain significance', 'PVS1=0', 'PS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', 'PM=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', 'PP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', 'BA1=0', 'BS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', 'BP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\s+(?=[A-Z])
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/yOBtS8/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

**Python code**:

```py
import re
test_str = 'Uncertain significance PVS1=0 PS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] PM=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] PP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] BA1=0 BS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] BP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]'
matches = re.split(r'\s+(?=[A-Z])', test_str)
print(matches)
```

**Results**:

```
['Uncertain significance', 'PVS1=0', 'PS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', 'PM=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', 'PP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', 'BA1=0', 'BS=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]', 'BP=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]']
```

Comment: That's one beautiful explanation :o